# Trying to store a procedure in Oracle 11g to monitor tablespace storage

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I'm trying to store this code in Oracle and everytime I get an error of compilation. I search about storing procedures without parameters and I didn't find a solution to fix this.
Here is the procedure that I'm trying to store:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Espacio_libre
    BEGIN
    select df.tablespace_name "Tablespace",
    totalusedspace "MB Usados",
    (df.totalspace - tu.totalusedspace) "MB Libres",
    df.totalspace "MB Totales",
    round(100 * ( (df.totalspace - tu.totalusedspace)/ df.totalspace))
    "Pct Libre"
    from
    (select tablespace_name,
    round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) TotalSpace
    from dba_data_files 
    group by tablespace_name) df,
    (select round(sum(bytes)/(1024*1024)) totalusedspace, tablespace_name
    from dba_segments 
    group by tablespace_name) tu
    where df.tablespace_name = tu.tablespace_name;
    END Espacio_libre;

/
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: As "Walid El Oubaha" said - you can not use SELECT in PL/SQL block without INTO clause.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a stored procedure in oracle, you are using PL/SQL code instead of SQL.
There is no select column,[column] from table in pl/SQL
You have to do 'Select column into variable from table'.
Please see the documentation below to learn elementary of PL/SQL programming.
[https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm][1]

Answer (score 0):

```
 create GLOBAL TEMPORARY table test22jan16 (tablespace_name varchar2(100),MB_Libres varchar2(100),MB_Totales varchar2(100),Pct_Libre varchar2(100))
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

insert into test22jan16 
    select df.tablespace_name ,
    (df.totalspace - tu.totalusedspace),
    df.totalspace,
    round(100 * ( (df.totalspace - tu.totalusedspace)/ df.totalspace))
    from
    (select tablespace_name,
    round(sum(bytes) / 1048576) TotalSpace
    from dba_data_files 
    group by tablespace_name) df,
    (select round(sum(bytes)/(1024*1024)) totalusedspace, tablespace_name
    from dba_segments 
    group by tablespace_name) tu
    where df.tablespace_name = tu.tablespace_name;
```

create a Global Temporary Table which stores the data then store the data in this table using above query

Comment: Why will a GTT help? This won't provide anything extra.

Comment: I thought he wants to store the data and provide the report using that. However that can also be done without using GTT

Answer (score 0):

Create a view, it'll do what you are expecting from this procedure.

You cannot just have a select statement in a PL/SQL block without an `INTO` clause and variable.

You could also create a Refcursor as an `OUT` paramter